# AWS AMI not working for another Domain unable to restart apache

Tags: server, apache2, aws, fedora, domain-server

I had created AWS AMI of my existing test server and created new server for development. At path `/etc/httpd/conf.d`  i have a configuration files named as `domain.com.conf`. which already includes

```
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com
```

Here i replaced test domain to dev domain name.
FYI: I am using `"fedora" VERSION_ID="2016.03"`

While restarting apache with command `sudo apachectl restart`

```
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Domain.com for ServerName
[Mon Mar 26 07:38:29 2018] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Mon Mar 26 07:38:29 2018] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Mon Mar 26 07:38:29 2018] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts
[Mon Mar 26 07:38:29 2018] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Mon Mar 26 07:38:29 2018] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts
```

Comment: You will probably have better luck at the [U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com), as AskUbuntu only covers Ubuntu.

Comment: @vidarlo I agree,thanks for your concern, but this issue could occur on both of the server regardless of OS either it is Ubuntu or Fedora. Answer would be helpful for both as this issue was due to firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After putting lots of efforts with many possible solution a found actual cause of error and solution.

**Cause**: Due to blocked port 443 for https and port 80 which is for http, it was not working on world wide.

**Solution**:

1. Go to EC2 dashboard (inside services section) in AWS console.
2. Select security group (From side bar).
3. Select instance from list of available ec2 instance.
4. Add Inbound Rules for http (port 80) and https (port 443).

Now try to hit domain URL on browser. It works.